# How to make journald increase logs storage capacity?

Tags: logs, storage, systemd-journald

I would like to have persistent logs via journald. I created `/var/log/journal` and reloaded the service. Now logs are saved on the disk. But the log size limit is low.

I added `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. (`Storage=persistent/auto` doesn't matter, I tried both).

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitInterval=30s
#RateLimitBurst=1000
#SystemMaxUse=
SystemKeepFree=10G
SystemMaxFileSize=1G
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
```

As you can see I only changed each journal file size to 1Gb and told that I want 10Gb free on the disk.

But `journald` tells me that he only has 4Gb log storage capacity.

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-journald
...
jan 20 15:44:26 host systemd-journald[1218]: System journal (/var/log/journal/) is 4.5G, max 4.0G, 0B free.
jan 20 15:44:26 host systemd-journald[1218]: Journal started
```

What did I miss?

```
$ systemctl --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

Comment: [The first pair defaults to 10% and the second to 15% of the size of the respective file system, **but each value is capped to 4G**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean that 4Gb is the maximum space can be occupied by the log?

Answer (score 6):

It's necessary to setup `SystemMaxUse=100G` e.g.

Comment: Is this true? can it really go beyond 4G?

Comment: Seems to be able to go over 4G

Comment: If you set a value with % (e.g. `12%`), it is capped to 4G. If you set a value with G (e.g. `20G`), it is respected.

Answer (score 1):

From the [man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) page:

> SystemMaxUse=, SystemKeepFree=, SystemMaxFileSize=, SystemMaxFiles=,
>   RuntimeMaxUse=, RuntimeKeepFree=, RuntimeMaxFileSize=,
>   RuntimeMaxFiles=
>
> [...]
>
> The first pair defaults to 10% and the second to 15% of the size of the respective file system, but each value is capped to 4G. If the
>   file system is nearly full and either SystemKeepFree= or
>   RuntimeKeepFree= are violated when systemd-journald is started, the
>   limit will be raised to the percentage that is actually free. This
>   means that if there was enough free space before and journal files
>   were created, and subsequently something else causes the file system
>   to fill up, journald will stop using more space, but it will not be
>   removing existing files to reduce the footprint again, either.

So yes, it maxes out at `4G`, **however**, the following is interesting in your case:

> journalctl and systemd-journald ignore all files with names not ending
>   with ".journal" or ".journal~", so only such files, located in the
>   appropriate directories, are taken into account when calculating
>   current disk usage.

So, moving the log files regularly allows you to circumvent the limitation. Note that **you** will have to then ensure the logs do not fill up your file system somehow, removing old log files! You could, say have 1 file max 1G, then check regularly and move the file to `${filename}.n` where `n` is 1-9, thus having max 10G ... provided you move the files when they reach `1G` in size to the oldest `${filename}.n`. To read the logs, you disregard the name, just oldest to youngest ...

Comment: Eventually the deal in `SystemMaxUse=`, thanks

Comment: I think if that is the case, then the man page is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to also raise `SystemMaxFiles` since systemd will start removing journal files from `/var/log/journal/*/` folder before it reaches the `System{MaxUse/KeepFree}` limit because it's ran out of the number of journal files.

On my system, each file in `/var/log/journal/*/systemd@*.journal` was capped at `129Mb` and with a default limit of only 100 `SystemMaxFiles`, the amount of logs stored was effectively capped at ~13Gb despite setting `SystemMaxUse` to `50G`.